# C++ How to align multiple output?

Tags: c++

I have a problem to solve where I need to show the output in this format:
[image: Output Format]

But the problem I am facing is that for `Purchase ID: 2`, which has two book title, the second book title (Midnight Library) is shown in second line and does not align properly, how can I align it under the `Book Title`?

Code:

```
void viewPurchase() //View all purchase transactions
{
    system("cls");
    struct purchaseInfo* viewPurchase;
    viewPurchase = head;
    int choice;

    cout << "*************" << endl;
    cout << "VIEW PURCHASE" << endl;
    cout << "*************" << endl;
    cout << "1. View Purchase" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "0. BACK TO MENU" << endl;
    cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        if (viewPurchase == NULL) {
            cout << "No record in the list\n";
            cout << "\nPress ENTER to Back to Menu...\n" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cin.get();
        }

        while (viewPurchase != NULL) {
            cout << "============================================================================\n";
            cout << "Purchase ID \tBook Title \t\t      Total Item \tTotal Price\n";
            cout << "============================================================================\n";
            while (viewPurchase != NULL) {
                cout << left << setw(16) << viewPurchase->purchaseID;
                    for (int loop = 0; loop < viewPurchase->size; loop++) {
                        cout << left << setw(30) << viewPurchase->book[loop].bookTitle;
                        if (loop == 0) {
                            cout << left << setw(18) << viewPurchase->totalItem;
                            cout << left << setw(16) << viewPurchase->totalPrice;
                        }
                        cout << endl;
                    }
                viewPurchase = viewPurchase->next;
            }
        }           
        break;
    }
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        cout << "\nInvalid selection. Press ENTER to continue...\n" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin.get();
        break;
    }
};
```

Anything need to change for this code?
`cout << left << setw(30) << viewPurchase->book[loop].bookTitle;`

Comment: your code is not compiling, please add the missing parts

Comment: The issue is that you only write the purchase ID once before the loop.  If you want subsequent loop iterations to display correctly then if `loop` is _not_ zero you'll need to make up the missing space in that column.  For example, you could do something like `cout << setw(16) << "";`

Comment: I would recommend that you avoid using hard-coded values for your column widths.  Instead, declare some constants for each column width.  Note also these might not align with your headings since that is using tab characters (whose width tends to be open for interpretation, despite being conventionally 8 characters).  You could instead write the headers the same way: `cout << setw(colWidthPID) << "Purchase ID" << setw(colWidthTitle) << "Book Title" << setw(colWidthItemCount) << "Total Item" << ...`

Comment: in c++20 you could use std::format

Comment: @paddy thank you so much for your help!! I have settled my problem!! <3 Your information is very useful for me!

Comment: @yaodav thanks for trying to help me!! I have settled my problem!! <3

Comment: @martin thanks for trying to help me!! I have settled my problem!! <3

Answer (score 2):

> but the second book title (Midnight Library) run away and does not align properly, how can I align it under the book Title?

Insert an empty string, using `setw` matching the width of the first column before inserting the book title.

Comment: thanks you so much for helping me!! I have settled my problem!! <3